# Python reverse engineering - why the code produced this particular result

Tags: python, if-statement, modulo

I was asked a question about why the following code gives the following result:

```
def find(j):
    if(j>1):
        j=find(j//10)-(j%10)
        print(j)
    else:
        j=0
    return j
i=122
k=find(i)
```

RESULT:

```
-2
-4
```

Why that particular result? Here is what I have so far:

`def find(j)` – defying function find with j being an argument
if j is greater than 1, the argument j within find function is divided by 10
122 % 10 = 2
`print (j)` – calls function find to display

From this point on, I am struggling. Why -2 and where is -4 coming from?

Comment: In Python 2, 12/10 = 1 (not 1.2).

Comment: A good Stack Overflow question is written so its answers will be helpful to others. If you figured out what specific operation's output was surprising, you could ask a question that was useful to people who had different code than what you're trying to do by asking about that operation itself, rather than about the code in which it was observed.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/JlFopV for an example of your code with a print statement that makes it easier to understand what's happening.

Comment: (See also [How should "Please explain how ${this code dump} works?" questions be handled?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta], explaining why such questions are categorically too broad to be on-topic unless they ask a narrow, specific technical question).

Comment: Please why does the title says "Python Reverse Engineering" ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is likely due to a Python version difference.  Modern versions of Python treat `/` as float division even if the operands are ints.  Python 2 did the equivalent of `//` (int division) if the operands were ints.

If I modify your code to use int division (which seems like it was probably the intent, since it also uses the `%` operator) then I get the expected results:

```
>>> def find(j):
...     if(j>1):
...         j=find(j/10)-(j%10)
...         print(j)
...     else:
...         j=0
...     return j
...
>>> find(122)
-1.22
-3.419999999999999
-5.419999999999999
-5.419999999999999
>>> def find(j):
...     if(j>1):
...         j=find(j//10)-(j%10)
...         print(j)
...     else:
...         j=0
...     return j
...
>>> find(122)
-2
-4
-4
```

Comment: I see, thanks. What about the result? Why -2 and -4? I understand so far: def find(j) – defying function find with j being an argument if j is greater than 1, the argument j within find function is divided by 10

print (j) – calls function find to display

Comment: Where does the OP say that the given results are in fact expected ones?

Comment: It's hard to answer the question "why these results" without either just saying "that's the only possible result this code can yield given that input", which is a copout, or just walking through the code line by line, which I can't really do all in the space a comment.  I suggest walking through the code line by line on your own, and posting another question if there's a particular line that's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A version of your code modified to explain what it's doing and why follows:

```
def find(j):
    if(j>1):
        find_result = find(j//10)
        new_j = find_result - (j%10)
        print("j == %r; find(%r) => %r; find(%r) - %r => %r" % (
            j, (j//10), find_result, (j//10), j % 10, new_j))
        j = new_j
    else:
        j=0
    return j

i=122
k=find(i)
```

...its output is as follows:

```
j == 12; find(1) => 0; find(1) - 2 => -2
j == 122; find(12) => -2; find(12) - 2 => -4
```

---

So: First, you start with `j=122`. It thus calculates `find(12)` and subtracts `2` from the result. So before we know what that will do, we need `find(12)`.

`find(12)` checks if `j > 1`. Because `1` is not `> 1`, this is false, so it returns `0`. The caller than subtracts 2 from this, getting `-2`, which it prints.

Then, `find(122)` takes this result of `-2`, and subtracts an additional `2` from it, so it gets `-4`.